# Does updating statistics recompile stored procedures in sql server

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Does updating statistics recompile stored procedures in sql server or even after updating statistics( Auto or manual) the procedures run with the same execution plan it first compiled with?

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN has a lengthy article on that.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)  To sum it up:

> Therefore, plan optimality-related reasons have close association with
>   the statistics.

Looks like it depends on how much the statistics changed.  So updating statistics may lead to a recompile but does not have to. To force removal of all cached query plans, [you can run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Comment: So after clearing proccache.. will the already compiled Sps recompile when I execute an SP?